# What is the difference between these two pieces of code?

Tags: c#

```
int[] div = new int[] {2,3,5};
IEnumerable<int> seq = new int[] {10,15,20,25,30};
int x;
for (int i=0; i<div.Length; i++){
  x = div[i];
  seq = seq.Where( s=> s%x ==0);
}
seq = seq.ToList();
```

AND

```
int[] div = new int[] {2,3,5};
IEnumerable<int> seq = new int[] {10,15,20,25,30};
for (int i=0; i<div.Length; i++){
  int y = div[i];
  seq = seq.Where( s=> s%y ==0);
}
seq = seq.ToList();
```

The first seq's final value is 10,15,20,25,30 and the second one's is 30.
I'm a little confused about the difference between `int x;`
and  `int y = div[i];` . Can someone explain this to me?
Thanks!

Comment: This must be a duplicate from somewhere... basically in the first case, all the lambda expressions are capturing the same variable. In the second, each lambda expression captures a different variable.

Comment: Check this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp) @JonSkeet explains there what's happening - you have the same case. Btw as far as I remember, this is not the case in `.NET 4.5+` anymore, both code blocks would have same results.

Comment: @Michael: No, a) it's not a difference in .NET 4.5, it's a difference in C# 5 regardless of the target framework; b) the difference is in how `foreach` loops are handled, and there isn't one here.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for clarification. Not sure I follow point `b)`. Are you suggesting in C# 5 this behavior will be still different for `for`, `while` loops (btw going to fire up Visual Studio and check for myself, but would like to see your input on this) ?

Comment: @Michael: Yes, variables declared inside a loop effectively behave differently to those declared outside a loop, in terms of capture. C# 5 just changed whether the `foreach` iteration variable counted as "inside" or "outside".

Comment: @JonSkeet I see now, thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Invoking `seq = seq.Where( s=> s%x ==0);` does not iterate over elements. It only creates an `IEnumarable` encapsulating the iteration, that can be iterated in fututre.

So if you declare your `x` variable before the loop, the lambda, that you passed in `Where()` uses the same variable. Since you are changing its value in a loop, eventually only the last one will be actually used.

Instead of expression like:

```
seq.Where( s=> s % 2 == 0).Where( s=> s % 3 == 0).Where( s=> s % 5 == 0);
```

you get:

```
seq.Where( s=> s % 5 == 0).Where( s=> s % 5 == 0).Where( s=> s % 5 == 0);
```

Comment: I am bit confused over here when the OP  uses `int y` the last value  is captured which is `5`..so the seq {10,15,20,25,30} is executed against '5' .But how does that  explain output to be `30` ?

Comment: No, in the second example variable is 2, 3 and then 5. Only 30 is dividible by all of these numbers.

Comment: Variable `y` is defined **inside** the loop code block, so lamba uses different value for every iteration.

Answer (score 2):

The result is different because you are using lambda expression in the LINQ's `Where()` parameter. The actual execution of the all lambdas in `Where()`'s is performed on the very last row of both examples - the line where you perform `.ToList()`. Have a look at the [Variable Scope in Lambda Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

The difference in the examples is how you initialize `x/y`.

In the first example there is only one memory slot for the variable `x` regardless of number of iterations of the `foreach`. The `x` always points to the same spot in the memory. Therefore there is only one value of the `x` on the last row and it is equal to the `div[2]`.

In the second example there is separate memory slot created for `y` in each iteration of the loop. As the program evaluates, the address where `y` points to is changed in every iteration of the `foreach`. You might imagine it as there are multiple `y` variables like `y_1`, `y_2`,... Hence when evaluating the actual lambdas in `Where()`s the value of the `y` is different in every one of them.